# submenu in ActionBar Tabs android code

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, submenu

i've used the existing model of Tab menu (the action bar) , and now i'm having problem adding  submenu to each tab , how can i do that ?

this is my code :

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager
    .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
    });
    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.
        Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
        tab.setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i));
        tab.setTabListener(this);       
        actionBar.addTab(tab);
    }
}
```

this is menu/main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings">
    </item>
</menu>
```

here is the rest of code :

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);


        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
        // the ViewPager.

        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

   /**
 * 
 */


    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
            // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
     * displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
                    container, false);
            TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                    .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                    ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

i'm waiting your answers , thanks

Comment: what is issue?? you have to just add '@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
  return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 }'

Comment: thanks for your answer , i already have this method when i try to add submenu to that menu it goes to option menu not to contextMenu ( Action Bar tab )  do you see what i mean ?

Comment: can you explain more..??

Comment: I've edited the question and added the rest of code

Comment: you need different menu subitem for different tab? m i right??

Comment: yes i need different submenu for ActionBar tab items  and the onCreateOptionsMenu dosen't work for that it add submenu to option item .

Comment: cause i have two menu actionBar Tab   and  OptionMenu i'm trying to add submenu to actionBar items not to optiobmenu items

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your tabs having their own class extending fragments, you simply include:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.yourmenu, menu);
    this.menu = menu;
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection

}
```

Edit: I just saw you are looking for a sub menu. Try this tutorial:  http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/07/android-options-menu-submenu-group.html
and take a look at "Options Menu Layout optionmenu.xml"

---

You will need to use fragments for each Tab.

Your MainActivity- Class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //instantiate Fragments / Tabs
    Fragment tabonefragment = new TabOneFragment();
    Fragment tabtwofragment = new TabTwoFragment();

    PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPagerAdapter.addFragment(tabonefragment);
    mPagerAdapter.addFragment(tabtwofragment);

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

// When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager
   .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
     });


    //adding tabs to your action bar
    ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    Tab tab1 = ab.newTab().setText("tabonetext")
            .setTabListener(new TabListener<TabOneFragment>(
                    this, "tab_one", TabOneFragment.class));

    Tab tab2 = ab.newTab().setText("tabtwotext")
            .setTabListener(new TabListener<TabTwoFragment>(
                    this, "tab_two", TabTwoFragment.class));

    ab.addTab(tab1);
    ab.addTab(tab2);
  }

public static class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private Fragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    /** Constructor used each time a new tab is created.
      * @param activity  The host Activity, used to instantiate the fragment
      * @param tag  The identifier tag for the fragment
      * @param clz  The fragment's Class, used to instantiate the fragment
      */
    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
    }

    /* The following are each of the ActionBar.TabListener callbacks */

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // Check if the fragment is already initialized
        if (mFragment == null) {
            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            ft.attach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0,
            android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1)
    {
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1)
    {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(arg0.getPosition());
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0,
            android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1)
    {           
    }
}

 public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private final ArrayList<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
            mFragments.add(fragment);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragments.get(position);
        }
    }
```

Your Fragment class:

```
public class TabOneFragment extends Fragment {

 @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
            //inflate your layout from  a tab_one_layout.xml file (or use the same xml of your R.layout.activitiy_main if you want)
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_one_layout, container, false);


    return view;
}

}


//HERE: individual options menu of TabOne
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.yourmenu, menu);
    this.menu = menu;
   //create some submenu if you want


    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection

}
```

That should do. The same/similiar code also for TabTwo ofc.

Comment: Please check the rest of code i've added , cause i my menu is built with code not xml !

Comment: Uhm, I can't see where you built the menu with code :0. Anyway, did you try [addSubMenu-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#addSubMenu%28int,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) ? Like SubMenu submenu = yourmainmenu.addSubMenu(...) ?

Comment: Tabs are built here  :   // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
  for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
   // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
   // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
   // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
   // this tab is selected.
   Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
   tab.setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i));
   tab.setTabListener(this);  
   actionBar.addTab(tab);
   
  }

Comment: I've already tried to use addSubMenu in onCreateOptionsMenu and it's added to optionMenu .. but i want to add submenu to ActionBar Tab !

Comment: Ok, after re-reading your questions a 4th time, I think I may got you wrong. My code provides an options menu for each Tab individually. Not sure if that fits your intentions as well.

Comment: PagerAdapter dosen't take any parameter in construcion (new)

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to include some code into MainActivity.class. It should work now. Also delete android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter import.

Comment: i've tried it , i can see added tab but not submenu , beside this is a lot of code just to add a submenu to tab!! is there a simple why . thanks for yours answers .

Comment: You can add a submenu with: SubMenu submenu = menu.addSubMenu(...) in your Fragment class but that is not needed anymore if you got a individual options menu (imo). I know its a lot of code, but it makes your structure more clear and modulized. I can't think of an easier way if you can't address each Tab one by one :(. I mean... in your code you also have a DummySectionFragment Class in your main activity which is also for this purpose.

Comment: Well, you could make a switch-case though. And depending on which tab you are having selected you could add a sub menu dynamically. Something like: `switch (getcurrentTab()) { case Tab1: //add submenu` etc.

Comment: I've posted an other answer to modify class DummySectionFragment  and the xml that i think is related to that and showing textview so i'll replace it with menu ?

Comment: i forgot to tell you that your code isn't working i get a lot of erros like methode ontabselected is duplicated etc...

Comment: Hmm. Thats weird. Maybe you have to delete some imports first because in my code I use my own TabListener and PageAdapter, so I am not using that from Google (so e.g. delete that line: import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter; and so on). Maybe I overlooked something because I copied and pasted that code from some more complex program that I wrote.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers , i deleted tabed menu since i'm not professionnel with android and having headache to make it work so i  used the normal menu wich is  more easy than this nice tabed menu .

Answer (score 0):

I think i should edit this code :

```
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
                    container, false);
            TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                    .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                    ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

and the XML file and replacte textview with a menu ?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$DummySectionFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</RelativeLayout>
```